# I don't get notifications for new questions (UX degradation)

Tags: bug, ignored-tags, live-refresh

Recently, `stackoverflow.com` (and some other sites) stopped showing summary bar for new questions.

A little research reveals that this happens when list of user-ignored tags is empty. If there is at least one ignored tag, then everything works fine. Something wrong with regex for an empty list.

[image: "7 questions with new activity" update shown]

To reproduce this issue, the "Hide questions in your ignored tags" option should be selected. Sites with these settings behave as described above.

[image]

When I was debugging code with *chrome devtools* I came across [this script](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/full.en.js?v=733d8f7ff638) with the `isIgnored` method which tests watched tags against regex `(?:)` (and always returns *true*) on sites with "Hide questions in your ignored tags" selected and an empty "ignored tags" list.

```js
isIgnored: function(e) {
  if (!k()) // <<<---------------
      return !1;
  var n = t(".js-ignored-tag-list .post-tag")
    , s = p(n, !0).split(/,(?!\s)/).map((e=>{
      const t = /^\[class\*=' t-(.+?)'\]$/
        , n = /^:regex\(class, t-(.+?)\)$/;
      let s;
      return s = t.test(e) ? e.match(t)[1] + ".*" : n.test(e) ? e.match(n)[1] : e.replace(/^\.t-/, ""),
      s = s.replace("ñ", "#").replace("ç", String.raw`\+`).replace("û", String.raw`\.`),
      new RegExp(s)
  }
  ));
  return s.length > 0 && e.some((e=>s.some((t=>t.test(e)))))
},

// ......
// this function checks "Hide questions in your ignored tags" flag
k = function() {
    return t(".js-hide-ignored").is(":checked")
}
```

Comment: I don't watch or ignore any tags here on MSE, and regularly get this update banner.

Comment: How exactly are you reproducing this? Which page are you on? Any filters applied? Which sorting is used?

Comment: [I went to the front page of MSE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXG2J.png) and I don't see any summaries. I didn't either watched nor ignored tags initially. I added an ignored tag and refreshed the page but there were still no summaries. I added a watched tag and refreshed - again no summaries (this is what you see in the screenshot). Is this what you mean? If so, under which circumstance do you even get summaries for the front page? If not, then which page is it?

Comment: @VLAZ https://stackoverflow.com/questions with `watched tags` filter. Same issue on https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions.

Comment: No repro: [Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QoxG.png) -> [After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yldep.png). I went to the questions page, clicked Filter, [selected my watched tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oj1IS.png), and applied the filter. Waited for new activity and clicked on the banner to load the new questions. All of the items had a summary. You can see that I do not have ignored tags in the first two screenshots. Am I trying to reproduce this correctly?

Comment: The [JavaScript tag page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) works fine when I access it while logged in with my main account (i.e. notification of new activity is shown; the page definitely subscribes the WebSocket for activity in the JavaScript tag; I have no watched tags and no ignored tags). However, when using a 21 rep test account and in incognito/private browsing mode, the page *does not* subscribe to *any* realtime WebSocket question activity feed, so can't show new activity live ("normal" would be to subscribe to the feed for the tag).